# How to safely run "myFilter.outputImage!, fromRect: myFilter.outputImage!.extent"?

Tags: ios, swift, cifilter

Sometimes, when I run my app, this line of code

```
let outputCGImage = context.createCGImage(myFilter.outputImage!, fromRect: myFilter.outputImage!.extent)
```

crashes the app, I do not know why =/

So, I want to safely run this line. I've tried `myFilter.outputImage?`, but it requires only `!`. So, how can I safely run those line?

I've wanted to try with the guard, but I do not want to pass those line. In this case my filter will not apply,in case of `return`, and I do not want that. I want to apply all my filters successfully.

Any improvements?

Comment: Well, what's the error message?

Comment: @AMomchilov got just this `#6
Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x000000010009617c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, I want to safely run this line.  I've tried:
>
> ```
> context.createCGImage(myFilter.outputImage?,
> ```

The first argument to createCGImage() is not an optional type, so you can't use the `?`.  You can use an if-let:

```
if let validImage = myFilter.outputImage {
    let outputCGImage = context.createCGImage(validImage, fromRect: validImage.extent)
}
else {
    //Do something else
}
```

Comment: My code looks like: `let outputCGImage = context.createCGImage(myFilter.outputImage!, fromRect: myFilter.outputImage!.extent)
        
        let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: outputCGImage, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
        
        return newImage`. So I need return an image

Comment: *So I need return an image*--Nothing is stopping you from doing that, but you can't return the image from `myFilter.outputImage` because sometimes there isn't one.  In that case, you'll have to create an image from something else.

Comment: yes, I know =/ So, if honestly, I want to know why it does not have sometimes. I do not want to show blank cell, I'm trying to return valid image each time

Comment: According to the CIFilter docs, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003960-RH2-SW26, the `outputImage` property is defined to be: `var outputImage: CIImage?`.